# Adding String to an unknown-size array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Im having some trouble with an Array in C++.
See I want to let the user give the program an input in form of a `String`, and keep doing it until the user is satisfied. My input is working fine but when i want to store the strings in to an array im running in to some problems. I have to define a size for my array apparently? and is there a way to store the input in 2 or 3 different `arrays` (depending on the input, which i sort with some if-statements) of strings, and the print them out?
My code looks something like this now..

```
string firstarray[10];
string secarray[10];

//The cin stuff here and reading strings from user-input

    if(MyCondition1){ 
for(int x = 0; x<=9;x++){ 
firstarray[x] = name;  
}

  if(MyCondition2){ 
    for(int x = 0; x<=9;x++){ 
    secarray[x] = name;  
    }
```

Is there a way to skip the 10-limit of an array? could it be like string

```
firstarray[];
```

?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with multiple arrays?  A vector<string> firstArray; gets rid of the size constraint.

Comment: You do mean `std::string`, right? I mean, I don't see a `using namespace` anywhere...

Comment: Well he's used string without std:: in the question.

Comment: didn't use std::, a bit new to c++ ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for a [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/). Or better, a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) which lets you access elements by their position.

Both of them can be expanded dynamically.

```
using namespace std;

// looks like this:
vector<string> firstvector;

firstvector.push_back(somestring); // appends somestring to the end of the vector

cout << firstvector[someindex]; // gets the string at position someindex
cout << firstvector.back(); // gets the last element
```

---

**About your second question:**
You can of course create several arrays / vectors to put your strings in. Maybe even use a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) of type `map<key, vector<string>>` where `key` can be an enum for the category (or a string, [but enum is better](http://www.builtsmart.com/pt/blog/default.aspx?id=1&t=Why-are-magic-strings-a-bad-thing)).

You put a new value into one of the vectors:

```
tCategoryEnum category = eCategoryNone;
switch(condition)
{
  case MyCondition1:
    category = eCategory1;
    break;
  case MyCondition2:
    category = eCategory2;
    break;
  // ...
}
// check if a category was found:
if(category != eCategoryNone)
{
    categoryMap[category].push_back(name);
}
```

Then to output this, you can simply loop over each category and vector element

```
for(int i = 0; i < categoryMap.size(); i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < categoryMap[i].size(); j++)
    cout << categoryMap[i][j];
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using an `std::vector<string> >` ?

Comment: i have encounterd it in some google-result. But i thought that it was to "over do it", guess i was wrong. Can some one link a how-to?

Comment: @Handsken no way is this overdoing it, vectors are simpler to use than arrays. Look at Martin's example it should get you on the right track.